# php file uploading

Tags: php, file-upload

file uploading in php we use HTML file tag, instead of file tag can i give direct path name...

normal procedure

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'path'.$_FILES['file']['name'])
```

is working fine...

instead i give like

```
move_uploaded_file(C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/images/img03.jpg,'path/img03.jpg')
```

is not working why?.......
I need to give path name like this only....
How i can do it....
Any other way is there for doing like dis....
it can support to local server to remote server

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding about how uploading files works

Answer (score 1):

See the first line in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

If the file wasn't uploaded, then it won't move it

What you want is rename:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

If you are going across a boundary that rename cannot cross, then you want [copy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) and [unlink()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that PHP is uploading the file to a temp path until it verifies everything went ok. That being said, you HAVE to specify the original temp path as the source, but you can alter the destination how you wish. try something like the following:

```
$newFile = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,Array('path','to',basename($_FILES['file']['name'])));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$newFile);
```

*I forget if you need basename, it's been a while since I've handled files in PHP. But this will allow you to change the "Destination" through `$fileName`*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to upload local file to remote server. You can write a function to simulate HTML form like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Upload local file to remote server
 *
 * @param   string   local file
 * @param   string   the target URL
 * @param   string   name of the form input (<input type="file" name="..." />)
 */
function send_file($filename, $target_url, $field_name)
{
    // Check if file exist
    file_exists($filename) OR die('Cannot find file');

    // Get file extension
    $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

    // Guess mimetype, add more mimetypes here
    if ($ext == 'jpg') {
        $mime = 'image/jpg';
    } else if ($ext == 'gif') {
        $mime = 'image/gif';
    } else if ($ext == 'png') {
        $mime = 'image/png';
    } else {
        $mime = 'text/plain';
    }

    // Extract URL to local variables
    extract(parse_url($target_url));

    // Build request header and body
    $boundary = '---------'.str_replace('.', '', microtime());
    $reqbody  = '--'.$boundary."\r\n"
              . 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="'.$field_name.'"; filename="'.$filename.'"'."\r\n"
              . 'Content-Type: '.$mime."\r\n\r\n"
              . file_get_contents($filename)."\r\n"
              . '--'.$boundary.'--'."\r\n";
    $bodylen  = strlen($reqbody);
    $reqhead  = 'POST '.(isset($path) ? $path : '/').' HTTP/1.1'."\r\n"
              . 'Host: '.$host."\r\n"
              . 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary."\r\n"
              . 'Content-Length: '.$bodylen."\r\n"
              . 'Connection: Close'."\r\n\r\n";

    // Open socket connection to remote host
    $fp = fsockopen($host, isset($port) ? $port : 80) OR die ('Cannot connect');

    fputs($fp, $reqhead);
    fputs($fp, $reqbody);

    // ...Read response here...

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
send_file('C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/images/img03.jpg', 'http://example.com/upload.php', 'file');
```

Where the script at `http://example.com/upload.php` contains:

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'path/for/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])
?>
```